# Numpy append array isn't working

Tags: python, numpy

Why isn't it appending all the lists?

```
test = {'file1':{'subfile1':[1,2,3],'subfile2':[10,11,12]},'file5':{'subfile1':[4,678,6]},'file2':{'subfile1':[4,78,6]},'file3':{'subfile1':[7,8,9]}}
testarray = np.array([50,60,70])
for file in test.keys():
    print(test[file]['subfile1'])
    subfile1 = np.append(testarray, test[file]['subfile1'])
print(subfile1)
```

Comment: What is it doing?  Don't just show the code.  Show the results and explain what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[`numpy.append`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) returns *a new NumPy array*, while your code shows that you think it's adding new values to `testarray`. The array is not appended in-place, a *new array* has to be created and filled with data, thus copying both `testarray` and `test[file]['subfile1']`.

Also, note that there's no need to loop over keys and extract a value from the dictionary by one of these keys. You can loop over the *items* the array contains, including both keys and values:

```
for key, value in test.items():
    print(value['subfile1'])
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than repeatedly concatenating lists to an array, collect the values in a list, and build the array just once.  It is faster, and less prone to errors:

```
In [514]: test
Out[514]: 
{'file1': {'subfile1': [1, 2, 3], 'subfile2': [10, 11, 12]},
 'file2': {'subfile1': [4, 78, 6]},
 'file3': {'subfile1': [7, 8, 9]},
 'file5': {'subfile1': [4, 678, 6]}}
In [515]: data=[test[f]['subfile1'] for f in test]
In [516]: data
Out[516]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 78, 6], [7, 8, 9], [4, 678, 6]]
In [517]: np.array(data)
Out[517]: 
array([[  1,   2,   3],
       [  4,  78,   6],
       [  7,   8,   9],
       [  4, 678,   6]])
```

If you must, build the list iteratively:

```
In [518]: data=[]
In [519]: for f in test.keys():
     ...:     data.append(test[f]['subfile1'])
```

You could concatenate at each step:

```
In [521]: testarray=np.array([50,60,70])
In [522]: for file in test.keys():
     ...:     testarray = np.concatenate((testarray, test[file]['subfile1']))
     ...:     
In [523]: testarray
Out[523]: 
array([ 50,  60,  70,   1,   2,   3,   4,  78,   6,   7,   8,   9,   4,  678,   6])
```

Notice this puts all values in one 1d array, as opposed to a 2d array that the previous methods did. We can `vstack` to go 2d (it too uses `concatenate`).

```
In [525]: testarray=np.array([50,60,70])
In [526]: for file in test.keys():
     ...:     testarray = np.vstack((testarray, test[file]['subfile1']))
     ...:     
     ...:     
In [527]: testarray
Out[527]: 
array([[ 50,  60,  70],
       [  1,   2,   3],
       [  4,  78,   6],
       [  7,   8,   9],
       [  4, 678,   6]])
```

I could also write this with `append`, but I'd rather not.  Too  many posters misuse it.