# numpy array append is not working

Tags: python, numpy

i am trying to append in numpy array.it does not showing any error but not appending the values in the array. i can't  understand what's the reason.

```
ind=[]
ind=np.array(ind)
ind

out:array([], dtype=float64)
rand_num
out:0.2581020651429914

for i in T_Yk:
    print i,rand_num,i>=rand_num
    if i>=rand_num:
        np.append(ind,i)


0.841407208505 0.258102065143 True
0.544017164891 0.258102065143 True
0.847014100035 0.258102065143 True
0.837888398913 0.258102065143 True
0.602345432651 0.258102065143 True
0.758088894007 0.258102065143 True
0.875552313712 0.258102065143 True
0.566129640396 0.258102065143 True
0.398095901072 0.258102065143 True
0.708554596955 0.258102065143 True
0.308165627166 0.258102065143 True
0.716732072072 0.258102065143 True
0.760848001298 0.258102065143 True
0.307696603977 0.258102065143 True
0.574524448748 0.258102065143 True
0.608537650411 0.258102065143 True
0.661614576393 0.258102065143 True
0.358783413082 0.258102065143 True
0.396823316883 0.258102065143 True
0.867563492221 0.258102065143 True
0.520237352281 0.258102065143 True
0.866000916749 0.258102065143 True
0.851035162881 0.258102065143 True
0.566755675099 0.258102065143 True
0.687814928058 0.258102065143 True
0.787882814547 0.258102065143 True
0.8790451058 0.258102065143 True
0.538294379248 0.258102065143 True
0.543694673875 0.258102065143 True
```

but when i print the array ind,it shows

```
array([], dtype=float64)
```

Comment: You did not read the np.append docs.  It is better use list append, and do one catenated at end

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646726/unsuccessful-append-to-an-empty-numpy-array  (and many other questions); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961972/numpy-append-array-isnt-working

Answer (score 7):

`np.append`, unlike `list.append`, is *not* an in-place operation.

Therefore, assign back to original pointer:

```
ind = np.append(ind, i)
```